# Embed tclsh in tk

Tags: interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

Is it possible to embed tclsh in Tk? I'm trying to send commands from a user interface made by tk and observe its results.

If so, could you help to pose some simple codes for this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the interp command to create and manipulate tcl interpreters:

http://wiki.tcl.tk/1477

You should be able to first create a interpreter this way and evaluate strings from your Tk Application.

1. create a interpret
2. Get the to evaluated string from your Tk application
3. evaluate the string in this interpreter

A minimal example to create an interpreter and evaluate a a string in it:

```
interp create a
set str "puts \"Hello World!\""
interp eval a $str
```

Comment: I am very new in Tcl. Could you show a simple code to demostrate how does it work? Thank you very much.

Comment: You should also catch the last line in case it will result in an interpreter error...

Comment: Yes. I made it from Tk. But how can i embed the tclshell into Tk directly? I don't want tclshell to run in a separate window. Thanks a lot.